# "operands do not match" assembler syntax error

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I wrote this code, in assembly, to calculate `(4*7)+5`, but I get these errors:

> (18) wrong parameters: MOV  ax,m1
>   (18) operands do not match: 16 bit register and 8 bit address.

```
 .MODEL SMALL
.stack 100h
.data
m1 DB 4
m2 DB 7
m3 DB 5
m4 DB ?
.code
main PROC
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    mov ax,m1
    mul ax,m2
    add ax,m3
    mov m4,ax 

     BEGIN ENDP
      END main
```

Comment: @movcmpret: no it won't.  This is x86 with MASM-like syntax.  The error is that symbol names magically get a size associated with them when declared that way, and `mov ax, m1` is doing a word load from a byte "variable", and the assembler stops you from making that mistake.  One solution is to use `dw` and make everything a word, or to use byte registers (`al`)

Comment: I am a beginner in the assembly language, can you help me?

Comment: I just edited my last comment.

Comment: I will trying now

Comment: I do it. But If i running the program I didn't now where i can see the result.

Comment: It's in `m4` where you stored it with `mov`, of course.  And also still in `al`.  Single-step your code with a debugger to see it, or set a breakpoint.

Comment: how can i store the result to memory?

Comment: `m4` *is* a memory location.  If you don't know what your code is already doing, you need a guide or tutorial, or a book.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for links.

Comment: I edit my code see.

Comment: Your edit makes no sense, and breaks the formatting, and wouldn't cause the error the text part of your question is asking about.  I reverted it instead of downvoting / voting to close what would have been a nonsense non-question.

Comment: The result now in register [ax] I want move it to memory

Comment: `mov m4,ax` already does that.

Comment: when I do compiler for the program,I have error (18) operands do not match: 16 bit register and 8 bit address

Answer (score 2):

Because all of the numbers involved {4,7,5} are very small, you get by with data definitions using `db`.
**But** this also means that the calculations should be byte-sized.

Write this instead:

```
mov al, m1
mul m2        ;Leaves m1 * m2 in AX (4*7=28 so AL=28 and AH=0)
add al, m3
mov m4, al
```

If you use a byte-sized operand (*m2*) with the `mul` instruction then `AL` is multiplied with it and the double-length product is stored in `AX`.